# PHP create a dbf file format for export

Tags: php, export, dbf

I'm trying to create a dbf file format using php, for download

But I dont know how to create a dbf file using php?

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the PHP manual, especially the section on [dbase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dbase.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Codeigniter v3.1.11 - Create .DBF file

<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use XBase\Enum\FieldType;
use XBase\Enum\TableType;
use XBase\Header\Column;
use XBase\Header\HeaderFactory;
use XBase\TableCreator;
use XBase\TableEditor;

class Test extends CI_Controller {    

    public function create()
    {
        // you can specify any other database version from TableType
        $header = HeaderFactory::create(TableType::DBASE_III_PLUS_MEMO);
        $filepath = 'C:/wamp64/www/utiamc/dbf/my_nse.dbf';

        $tableCreator = new TableCreator($filepath, $header);
                $tableCreator
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'   => 'SC_CODE',
                'type'   => FieldType::CHAR,
                'length' => 20,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'   => 'SC_NAME',
                'type'   => FieldType::CHAR,
                'length' => 50,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'   => 'SC_GROUP',
                'type'   => FieldType::CHAR,
                'length' => 10,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'   => 'SC_TYPE',
                'type'   => FieldType::CHAR,
                'length' => 20,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'QUOT_1',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'QUOT_2',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'QUOT_3',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'QUOT_4',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'          => 'TDCLOINDI',
                'type'          => FieldType::CHAR,
                'length'        => 20,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'NO_TRADES',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'NO_OF_SHRS',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))
            ->addColumn(new Column([
                'name'         => 'NET_TURNOV',
                'type'         => FieldType::NUMERIC,
                'length'       => 20,
                'decimalCount' => 2,
            ]))    
            ->save(); //creates file

        // $table = new TableEditor($filepath);
        //... add records 
    }

}
```